# How can I import a package from another gitlab repo into my own repo?

Tags: r, gitlab, rstudio

Scenario:

I have two gitlab projects, project A & B.

In project B I create a package and within that package a function called project_B_function.

In project A I create a package, project_A_package.

How can I tell the project_B_function it needs to import the project_A_package?

Currently, when I tell a function I've created which packages it needs from CRAN, I would write:

```
@import tidyverse
@import stringr
```

Is there an @..... option where I can point it to the project_A_package?

Comment: Not really. `@import` doesn't import a package from CRAN (or any other) repo, it loads the package from locally installed packages. Your project A package has to be installed locally -- then you can use functions defined in it. To install packages from other sources than CRAN please have a look on `{remotes}` package or `repos` option in `install.packages()` function.